# When are two selects on same page works only one(the second)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

If I add two select on the same page, in the first select not working ng-selected, only in the second select.
If I remove in the first select

```
ng-model="opcionSeleccionadaInicio"` ng-change="vm.modificarHoraInicio($index,opcionSeleccionadaInicio)"
```

The  ng-selected works, but I don't have any model and I can't handle when the user change the select.
This is my code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Cambiar horarios">
<ion-content>
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="dia in vm.dias">
        <div class="item item-divider" align="center">
            {{dia.nombre}}
        </div> 
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Primer turno
                </div>
               <select ng-model="opcionSeleccionadaInicio" ng-change="vm.modificarHoraInicio($index,opcionSeleccionadaInicio)"> 
                    <option ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" ng-selected="dia.valorInicio == horario">{{horario}}</option> 
                </select>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Último turno
                </div>
                <select ng-model="opcionSeleccionadaFin" ng-change="vm.modificarHoraFin($index,opcionSeleccionadaFin)"> 
                    <option ng-selected="dia.valorFin == horario"  ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" >{{horario}}</option> 
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-horizontal"><button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="vm.guardarHorarios()"> Guardar horarios </button></div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The first select show me the options, but not select a default value like the second select.

Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! There is not need to define a ng-selected, just define ng-model with the value what you want to modify. Also the option choose by default the value of the model.

This is my final code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Cambiar horarios">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list card" ng-repeat="dia in vm.dias">
            <div class="item item-divider" align="center">
                {{dia.nombre}}
            </div> 
            <div class="list">
                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label">
                        Primer turno
                    </div>
                   <select ng-model="dia.valorInicio" ng-change="vm.modificarHoraInicio($index,dia.valorInicio)"> 
                        <option ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios">{{horario}}</option> 
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label">
                        Último turno
                    </div>
                    <select ng-model="dia.valorFin" ng-change="vm.modificarHoraFin($index,dia.valorInicio)"> 
                        <option ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" >{{horario}}</option> 
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-horizontal"><button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="vm.guardarHorarios()"> Guardar horarios </button></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**// EDIT //**

Also, If someone use ng-options is the same:

```
<select ng-model="dia.valorInicio" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.modificarHoraInicio($index, dia.valorInicio)"></select>

<select ng-model="dia.valorFin" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.modificarHoraFin($index, dia.valorFin)"></select>
```

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code, we can use two `ng-selected`, just set their values different.

first: `<option ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" ng-selected="dia.valorInicio == horario">{{horario}}</option>`

second: `<option ng-selected="dia.valorFin == horario" ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" >{{horario}}</option>`

Check this link for further help:

https://plnkr.co/edit/3aH1dlJD43HUU2ZBuMXU?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What should I need to change? you said: "set ther values different", but I don't see any change on the code respect the value

Comment: Because both code are equals, there isn't change from my code